# Convert html into yii2 format

Tags: html, yii2

I have the following html and I have used it in my view but I want it in yii2 format.

```
<label id="rate" for="rate">Rate</label>
<input type="text" style="width: 345px; height: 35px;" name="contact" id="contact" value="" maxlength="255">
<span class="help-text"></span>
```

Comment: Your code seems missing.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question adding your code. Remember, SO isn't a free code service

Comment: You have to mark HTML as a code block, otherwise no-one can see it. I've edited your question, but  also you also need to update the question with more information, not post it as an answer. If that is an answer, it's not very clear what it is.

Comment: What do you mean with yii2 format? maybe you are looking for [active records](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'contact')->input([
    'template' => '<label id="rate" for="rate">{label}</label>{input}<span class="help-text"> 
</span><div>{error}</div>', 'maxlength' => true, 'id' => 'contact', 'style' => 
'width: 345px; height: 35px;'
])->label('Rate'); ?>



public function rules()
{
return [
     [['contact'], 'string',  'max' => 255],
];
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to this answer please.